# Where can I find a graded reader with pinyin alongside the simplified characters?

Tags: reading, books

Recently I started learning the Chinese language. So far I've been focusing on the spoken Mandarin, so there are many words for which I know pinyin but not the character. To build the associations I got a graded book that had both. However, to see the characters I needed to flip a page. It'd be more helpful for someone who already knows most of the characters, but when learning them from scratch, paging several times every line is too much.

Is there a book that has pinyin and characters on the same page or adjacent pages? Interspersed lines would be ideal.

Comment: Pleco (https://store.pleco.com/products.php?ios=1) does digital ones: *Graded Chinese Reader 500 Words*, *Graded Chinese Reader 1000 Words*, etc. They come with audio file downloads & you can check pinyin of anything by just clicking on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All, even higher "levels" of Graded Chinese Reader books come with pinyin. With a nice grid you can put over the page to cover pinyin (or characters) if you feel like it.

https://www.purpleculture.net/graded-chinese-reader-bs-660/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind, you might want Mandarin textbooks for lower grade elementary school used in China. 
And some storybooks also have Pinyin on every character.
You might search jd.com or taobao.com to find some examples using keywords like "识字 拼音", "小学 课本".

If you want get pinyin when reading on screen, you might try Lingoes Translator ([offical website](http://www.lingoes.cn/)) with Chinese Dictionary installed.  This software can pick up the character under your cursor and perform a query automatically (and you get pinyin)(this may require an option to be enabled).